# How to get data from object having array in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have data like this after using var_export function

```
Google_Service_Drive_FileList::__set_state(array(
    'collection_key' => 'items',
    'internal_gapi_mappings' => array() ,
    'etag' => NULL,
    'itemsType' => 'Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile',
    'itemsDataType' => 'array',
    'kind' => NULL,
    'nextLink' => NULL,
    'nextPageToken' => NULL,
    'selfLink' => NULL,
    'modelData' => array(
        'items' => array(
            0 => array(
                'id' => '1dOiZFO6nFEYKSLnMRS9mKZPXFBjztg_BwgEmNOPC2tQ',
                'title' => 'Php zend download',
                 )
) ,
    ) ,
    'processed' => array() ,
))
```

How could i get data from it. 
I am trying by storing it in variable `$response`

```
print_r($response->modelData['items']['0']['id']);
```

but getting nothing.

Comment: Now I tried `print_r($response['0']['modelData']['items']['0']['id']);` and getting `Notice: Undefined index: items`

Comment: [mcve]?  Where did `$response` come from?  What happens when you just try to `print_r ($response)`?

Comment: `$response` came from the response of api for file list

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things but didn't work. 
But Now I removed `var_export`
and used `$response['modelData']['items']['0']['id'];` where `$response` is an object type and it worked and gave me the value of `id`.

when printing only `print_r($response)` i am getting:

```
Google_Service_Drive_FileListObject([collection_key:
    protected ] => items[internal_gapi_mappings:
        protected ] => Array() [etag] => [itemsType:
            protected ] => Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile[itemsDataType:
                protected ] => array [kind] => [nextLink] => [nextPageToken] => [selfLink] => [modelData:
                    protected ] => Array(
                        [items] => Array(
                            [0] => Array(
                                [id] => 0BzwXST - A2MuCY0FOd3ZNUVJQYk0[webContentLink] => https: //docs.google.com/uc?id=0BzwXST-A2MuCY0FOd3ZNUVJQYk0&export=download [title] => aucti.pdf )
                                ) ,
                            ) ,
                            'processed' => array() ,
                        ))
```

But with var_export I was getting:

```
Google_Service_Drive_FileList::__set_state(array(
    'collection_key' => 'items',
    'internal_gapi_mappings' => array() ,
    'etag' => NULL,
    'itemsType' => 'Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile',
    'itemsDataType' => 'array',
    'kind' => NULL,
    'nextLink' => NULL,
    'nextPageToken' => NULL,
    'selfLink' => NULL,
    'modelData' => array(
        'items' => array(
            0 => array(
                'id' => '0BzwXST-A2MuCY0FOd3ZNUVJQYk0',
                'webContentLink' => 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0BzwXST-A2MuCY0FOd3ZNUVJQYk0&export=download',
                'title' => 'aucti.pdf',
            ) ,
        ) ,
    ) ,
    'processed' => array() ,
))
```

Comment: So did you answer your question?

Comment: Not the way i wanted but I have achieved what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Just select it as

```
$response['items'][0]['id']
```

Comment: it won't work. you should use integer value as key for numeric arrays. [0], but not ['0']

Comment: yes it is. I have corrected it. Earlier copied from the question section. Thanks for your comment.